# using require.js with FB SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, requirejs

I would like to load FB SDK using require.js.

my test case is something like this:

**test.js**:

```
require([        
     'libs/facebook/fb'
     ], function(FB){
     FB.api("/me", function(){});
));
```

I would like to have test.js run only after FB SDK is loaded, and have FB ready for it.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved? what should my wrapper (libs/facebook/fb.js) have?

Comment: Looks like Facebook has finally addressed this, their solution looks quite similar to some of the answers on this question. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howto/javascript/requirejs/

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't seem like the FB API is an AMD module, so it doesn't define itself in a manner to which RequireJS is accustomed to. You will need to shim the FB API using require.config. I'm assuming test.js is the script you have provided as the data-main value for RequireJS.

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'facebook' : {
            exports: 'FB'
        }
    },

    paths: {
        'facebook' : 'libs/facebook/fb'
    }
});

require(['facebook'], function(FB){
    FB.api('/me', function(){});
});
```

Comment: could you perhaps add more detail to this answer? What should libs/facebook/fb contain? The `FB.init()` code? A reference to `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js`?

Comment: libs/facebook/fb is the path to the fb module, or in this case the fb.js file. RequireJS assumes that everything is a module, and doesn't require you to include the .js part of the file path. It will detect that by itself.

Comment: Sorry, still a bit confused. Do you mean its a literal copy of this file: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js? If so where does the init code go? Just loading the library isn't enough to call `FB.api()`

Comment: You can include the complete URL to the all.js file instead of 'libs/facebook/fb' and RequireJS will load that file up asynchronously. Then you can call FB.api() where 'FB.api('/me', function(){});' currently is.

Comment: Doing it like that, `FB.api()` causes an error: `"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."`.  Pretty sure you need to call `FB.init()` first...

Comment: Sorry, I meant FB.init(), not FB.api().

Comment: If you make that edit in your Answer, and no-one else posts a crazy-good answer, I'll award you the bounty (can't give it to myself).

Comment: I built my answer based on what the OP posted. I haven't worked with the FB API before so I don't know how it works. I had a quick look at the code, and figured out that it's not an AMD module.

Comment: Your answer was the biggest help to me, and is the right approach AFAIK, but I feel uncomfortable awarding a bounty to an answer with code that doesn't actually work. I'll edit your question *for* you if you want, but I really think it should at least have `// FB.init({...})` in place of `FB.api`. This question has gotten quite a few views, so it could potentially be quite useful to searchers.

Comment: Sure. Like I said, I haven't worked with the FB API before, so I don't know how it's supposed to work. My answer is purely based on the code provided by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Or wrap the init code in a module (the sample uses Dojo):

```
define( 'facebook', 
    [ 'dojo/dom-construct', 
      'dojo/_base/window', 
      'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js' ], // remove "/debug" in live env
    function( domConstruct, win ) 
    {

        // add Facebook div
        domConstruct.create( 'div', { id:'fb-root' }, win.body(), 'first' );

        // init the Facebook JS SDK
        FB.init( {
            appId: '1234567890', // App ID from the App Dashboard
            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/facebook-channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
            status: true, // check the login status upon init?
            cookie: true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
            xfbml: true // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        } );


        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
        console.log( 'Facebook ready' );

        return FB;
    } 
);
```

Comment: It looks like the code here for adding the `fb-root` element here runs too late, as the Facebook SDK looks for that div after loading and automatically creates it if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: could you perhaps explain this code a bit? Does this prevent `FB` from being added to `window`? Is @DrakeHampton's comment correct? Any other implications?

Comment: I'm doing something very similar to this (sans Dojo) but FB is not available at the time I envoke `FB.init()`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Documentation from Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/requirejs/

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    'facebook' : {
      export: 'FB'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    'facebook': '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all'
  }
})
require(['fb']);
```

and then add the module like this:

```
define(['facebook'], function(){
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    channelUrl : '//yourdomain.com/channel.html'
  });
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: An edit was rejected commenting that there is a typo in facebook's manual claiming `require(['fb']);` should be `require(['facebook']);`. This may be true so it's worthy of a comment.

Comment: @Popnoodles: "require(['fb']);" is correct. fb is the name of the module file you create.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [voidstate's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398031/363701) and [Dzulqarnain Nasir's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11860033/363701) Answers, here is the code I ended up using on my project.

The part that tripped me up the most was that `FB.init()` is apparently asynchronous. In trying to envoke the `callback()` (without `FB.getLoginStatus`), `FB` was not yet initialized, and I was getting "`An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`" errors.

**RequireJS Shim Config**

```
require.config({
    // paths: { 'facebookSDK': '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug' }, // development
    paths: { 'facebookSDK': '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all' }, // production
    shim: { 'facebookSDK': { exports: 'FB' } }
});
```

**AMD Module to Initialize Facebook JS SDK**

```
define(['facebookSDK'], function (FB) {
    'use strict';

    return function (settings, callback) {
        var args = {
            appId: settings.appId,
            channelUrl: settings.channelUrl,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        };

        console.log('Calling FB.init:', args);
        FB.init(args);

        if (callback && typeof (callback) === "function") {
            // callback() // does not work, FB.init() is not yet finished
            FB.getLoginStatus(callback);
        }            
    };

});
```

This still doesn't quite address the Original Question's desired usage.

OP's code could maybe be rewritten as:

```
require(['libs/facebook/fb'], // where fb.js holds my above Module
   function(FBinit){
     FBinit({
       appId: appId, 
       channelUrl: channelUrl
     }, function(){
       FB.api("/me", function(){});
     });
   }
);
```

This isn't quite as cleanas OP's original concept, but its the best I could figure out. If anyone has any, I'd love some feedback or advice on how to improve my approach. I am still very much new to RequireJS.